# Default underline not visible in TextInput in React native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am new to React native development. In my application I have login page, in this login page two textinput. In this textinput not getting underline. I have tried many ways but not getting underline. Here my requirement is need underline of inputtext. So how to get this underline?

This is the my login form code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View,TextInput,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>SEDC</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Acct No/User Id" style={styles.textInput} multiline={true}></TextInput>
      <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.textInput}></TextInput>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={this.login}><Text>Log In</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  login=()=>{
    alert("testing......");
    // this.props.navigation.navigate('Second');
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },

  textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 50,
    borderBottomColor:'#000',
    margin:5,
    marginRight:50,
    // backgroundColor: '#000',
},
  btn:{
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#01c853',
    padding: 10,
    margin:10,
    marginLeft: 100,
    marginRight:100,
    alignItems: 'center',
}
});
```

This is the output of my code.

[image]

I have tried with borderBottomColor:'#000', but not working..So please guide me how to do this

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: have you tried with the prop **underlineColorAndroid** ex. <TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'rgb(0,0,0)'} />

Comment: Thanks @DheerajChaudhary It is working perfect

Answer (score 15):

In addition to setting the bottom border color, you'll also need to set the bottom border "width".

The `borderBottomWidth` property defines the thickness in pixels for the border, along the bottom edge of the textInput component. So for instance, you can apply a black border along the bottom of your `textInput`, with thickness of 2 pixels by making the following adjustment to your styles:

```
textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 50,
    borderBottomColor:'#000',
    margin:5,
    marginRight:50,

    borderBottomColor: '#000', // Add this to specify bottom border color
    borderBottomWidth: 2     // Add this to specify bottom border thickness
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working with.. borderBottomWidth: 1. but no need of backgroundColor

Comment: @rams ah, sorry about that - minor mistype there, I meant to also include in the answer that the `borderBottomColor` can be specified if needed as well. I've just updated - hope that helps!

Comment: @Denny yes, But when giving  borderBottomWidth: 1, getting first textinput line is thick color compared to second textinput. Do you know the reason

Comment: have you set `underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}` on both TextInput components?

Answer (score 5):

just set

```
underlineColorAndroid={'black'}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Its quite simple easy : we need to pass our custom style inside the TextInput layout and works done for showing under line**
*By this custom style we can perform 2 operation a.we can put underline b.we can also use boxes for our textinput field*

```
   bottomBorder: {
marginLeft: 20,
marginRight: 20,
borderBottomColor: 'skyblue',//if we want only bottom line
borderBottomWidth: 2, // Add this to specify bottom border thickness &
//textDecorationLine: 'underline',
//borderColor:"skyblue",//if we want to show our TextInput field inside the box
//borderWidth:2 //use this to show width of border boxes
}
```

**Now it time to put this custom Style into our TextInput layout**

```
<TextInput placeholder="Enter your Name "
      style={ styles.bottomBorder}
      onChangeText={(text) => {
        console.warn(text)
      }}
    />
```